# PHP:: cannot retrieve all values inside array

Tags: php, arrays, echo, pre, var-dump

Here is my simple code:

```
<?php

$components=array(
1 => 'Carrot', 'Apple', 'Orange',
2 => 'Boiled Egg', 'Omelet',
3 => 'Ice Cream', 'Pancake', 'Watermelon'
);

echo'<pre>';
var_dump($components);
echo'</pre>';
```

output :

```
array(6) {
  [1]=>
  string(6) "Carrot"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "Boiled Egg"
  [3]=>
  string(9) "Ice Cream"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "Omelet"
  [5]=>
  string(7) "Pancake"
  [6]=>
  string(10) "Watermelon"
}
```

1. Where is `'Apple'` & `'Orange'` ?
2. Why I cannot retrieve the a specific value from (for example : $components[1][2] = 'r') :/ Why ?!

Comment: what a fuss mate, is your array correct, once correct your array, it will work.

Comment: The answers to both questions can be found in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-60).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an array like this,

```
$components=array(
  1 => ['Carrot', 'Apple', 'Orange'],
  2 => ['Boiled Egg', 'Omelet'],
  3 => ['Ice Cream', 'Pancake', 'Watermelon']
);
```

And now check your array.

Comment: Working :) Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Need to wait 7 minutes to accept it (policy)... hmmm :/ ok... I'll wait

Answer (score 2):

From your given syntax, it's forming a single dimensional array, not a multi-dimensional array.

Try this:

```
$components=array(
    1 => array('Carrot', 'Apple', 'Orange'),
    2 => array('Boiled Egg', 'Omelet'),
    3 => array('Ice Cream', 'Pancake', 'Watermelon')
 );
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to organize your array like this:

```
$components = array(
   1 => array(
         1 => 'Carrot',
         2 => 'Apple',
         3 => 'Orange'
   ),
   2 => array(
         1 => 'Boiled Egg',
         2 => 'Omelet'
   ),
   3 => array(
         1 => 'Ice Cream',
         2 => 'Pancake',
         3 => 'Watermelon'
   ),
);
```

Then you'll be able to obtain: `$components[1][2] = 'Apple'`

Answer (score 1):

### You may use string into array index Like this

```
 <?php
$components=array(
1 => ['Carrot', 'Apple', 'Orange'],
2 => ['Boiled Egg', 'Omelet'],
3 => ['Ice Cream', 'Pancake', 'Watermelon']
);

echo "<pre>";
print_R($components);
```

?>

Comment: OP does NOT have any strings in there.  Those are array elements of string type

Comment: Yes @bub but i just answer your question Where is 'Apple' & 'Orange' ?

Comment: This is the way how you get all data according to your question .

Comment: I didn't have any question :) I just mentoined that your post does not provide an answer to OPs question